# dispose resource in C#

Tags: c#, dispose

```
ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar(obj);

if(_FileRead!=false)
{
    pBar.Text = langSupport.GetMessages("123", cultureName);
    pBar.ShowDialog();
}
```

In this example how I can dispose "pBar" resource. Below I have specifide 3 ways, which is the best way of object dispose?

1. `pBar.Dispose();`
2. `pBar = null;`
3. `pBar.Dispose();`
   `pBar = null;`

Comment: Like others points out using is the way to go but just FYI it uses try...finally + alternative 1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the creation of the `ProgressBar` in a [`using` statement.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
using(ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar(obj))
{
   if(_FileRead!=false)
   {
       pBar.Text = langSupport.GetMessages("123", cultureName);
       pBar.ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

Since it implements `IDisposable`, this is the best way to ensure proper disposal.

Comment: i think there may be some errors in your code, no closing ) and extra {

Answer (score 2):

If it supports it I would use:

```
using(ProgressBar pBar = new ProgressBar(obj))
{
  if(_FileRead!=false)
  {
      pBar.Text = langSupport.GetMessages("123", cultureName);
      pBar.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

In that way when it exits the using it disposes of all the relevant objects.